# Call webservice from JavaScript - error 500

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to call some 3rd party webservice. When I do this using Postman (addon to Google Chrome) everything works fine, but when I do this from JavaScript, it not work. I'm getting Internal Server Error (500). Why? What I'm doing wrong?

This is HTTP Request preview from Postman:

```
POST /ws/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: mobile.example.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/login
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> <SOAP-ENV:Body> <getUserInfo_server xmlns:="http://tempuri.org"> <__numeric_0> <login xsi:type="xsd:string">username</login> <pwd xsi:type="xsd:string">password</pwd> </__numeric_0> </getUserInfo_server> </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is code form JS:

```
var requestBody =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
        '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
            '<getUserInfo_server xmlns:="http://tempuri.org">' +
                '<__numeric_0>' +
                    '<login xsi:type="xsd:string">username</login>' +
                    '<pwd xsi:type="xsd:string">password</pwd>' +
                '</__numeric_0>' +
            '</getUserInfo_server>' +
        '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
    '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://mobile.example.com/ws/login.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
request.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/login');
request.send(requestBody);
```

I'm trying to use $.post, $.soap, $.ajax. I'm install addons to prevent CORS ([Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)).

Comment: did you get a CORS error? if so you should include your domain as a valid origin on the server conf.

Comment: I don't have access to server with webservice. As for CORS error, yes, I get CORS error when I try call webservice from JS (from Postman everything works fine, without errors). But when I install addon to my browser, I don't get CORS error - only Internal Server Error (500).

Answer (score 0):

Normally 500 errors are problems in the back-end, not in the frontend. So your request might be perfectly fine but something is crashing in the back-end. If you can check the logs in the server you might know the exact issue.